# pandas asof selecting next row instead of last

Tags: pandas

According to the documentation, asof() (not merge_asof) only returns the "last" row before the asof time, but no option to get the "next" row right after. How to achieve this behavior? Essentially just like parameter direction='forward' for the merge_of() function.

For example, the following should return value 40 and 50.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]},
               index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2018-02-27 09:01:00',
                                       '2018-02-27 09:02:00',
                                      '2018-02-27 09:03:00',
                                      '2018-02-27 09:04:00',
                                      '2018-02-27 09:05:00']))

df.asof(pd.DatetimeIndex(['2018-02-27 09:03:30',
                       '2018-02-27 09:04:30']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way `searchsorted`

```
s=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2018-02-27 09:03:30',
                       '2018-02-27 09:04:30'])
np.searchsorted(df.index,s)
array([3, 4])
df.iloc[np.searchsorted(df.index,s)]
                      a
2018-02-27 09:04:00  40
2018-02-27 09:05:00  50
```

Comment: Thanks. One issue is that for the edges, the index will go out of bounds and throw an error, while by default nan should be returned (e.g. '2018-02-27 09:06:00' in s). Is there an easy fix?

Comment: @iwbabn using np.clip by limit the max to the max of df index

Comment: but that will select the last row instead of nan? 09:06:00 is outside the dataset.